# Assign values to a tensor based on values from another tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I've got two tensors:

```
import keras as K
import tensorflow as tf

A=K.zeros((4,4))    
T=K.constant([0,1,2,2]) 

#do something

#expected result: 1 starting at the index in tensor T
'''
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],      <-- 1 starting at index(column) 0
   [0, 1, 1, 1],          <-- 1 starting at index(column) 1
   [0, 0, 1, 1],          <-- 1 starting at index(column) 2
   [0, 0, 1, 1]])         <-- 1 starting at index(column) 2

'''
```

The idea is to assign 1 to tensor A starting at the index contained in tensor T.
Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `tf.sequence_mask`.

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

A= K.zeros((4,4))
T= K.constant([0,1,2,2])

mask = tf.sequence_mask(T,A.shape[-1])
# [[False False False False]
#  [ True False False False]
#  [ True  True False False]
#  [ True  True False False]]
result = tf.where(mask,A,tf.ones_like(A))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(result))

[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats awesome

Comment: @JuanCastaño You're welcome. I corrected some code so that it fits your question better.

Comment: Super! One las question: now suppose that in the same setting, instead of assigning 1`s at the index, I`d had to insert values from another tensor, starting at the index. How can I do this?

Comment: @JuanCastaño I don't quite understand your question. Can you give an example?